# Judging the case accessing from iPhoneX PWA

Tags: mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I'm now testing PWA on iPhoneX.
My web app's UIs are positioned bottom most of the page, but in iPhoneX PWA, these UIs are conflicted with iOS's wipe gesture.

[image]

So, only in iPhoneX's PWA case, I want to position these UIs upper.
How can I judge the case accessing from iPhoneX PWA at client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 1 solution by using "display-mode", "width" and "height" media query:

```
@media screen and (display-mode: standalone) and (width: 375px) and (height: 768px),
  screen and (display-mode: standalone) and (width: 724px) and (height: 375px),
  screen and (display-mode: fullscreen) and (width: 375px) and (height: 768px),
  screen and (display-mode: fullscreen) and (width: 724px) and (height: 375px) {
    // put css code for iPhoneX PWA here.
}
```